# Will null always cause NullPointerException in switch statement in Java 8?

Tags: java-8, nullpointerexception, null, switch-statement

[Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) reads

> The `default` section handles all values that are not explicitly handled by one of the `case` sections.

However, when I ran the following code

```
Integer i = null;

switch (i) {
    case 1:
        // ...
        break;    
    default:
        System.out.println("default hit");
}
```

, `NullPointerException` was thrown. Will `null` always cause `NullPointerException` to be thrown or is there a possibility that it will hit `default` label in `switch` statement? I guess it should be also the case for any Java version prior to Java 18, where `null` matching was introduced.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: It would fail, while attempting to perform unboxing. With `String` or `enum` it would not work either.

Comment: when I tried it, I got NullPointerException

Comment: If you know that the answer to your question is "no", then why not rephrase your question? ;-)

Comment: @JoachimSauer, I rephrased it :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [relevant section of the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se19/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.11.3) says this:

> A switch statement is executed by first evaluating the selector expression. Then:
>
> - [...]
> - Otherwise, if the result of evaluating the selector expression is `null`, then a `NullPointerException` is thrown and the entire switch statement completes abruptly for that reason.

So a `null` value will never cause the `default` case (or any other case) to be executed.

Earlier, in a non-normative section the spec explains:

> *`null` cannot be used as a `case` constant because it is not a constant expression. Even if `case null` was allowed, it would be undesirable because the code in that case would never be executed. This is due to the fact that, given a selector expression of a reference type (that is, `String` or a boxed primitive type or an enum type), an exception will occur if the selector expression evaluates to `null` at run time. In the judgment of the designers of the Java programming language, propagating the exception is a better outcome than either having no case label match, or having the `default` label match.*